# Add a column value from another table as default constraint

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to add a default constraint to a table such that the value that will be used as default will be from another table's columns?

i have created a table `MY_TBL` in which having a column `CURRENCY_CD` which references `CURRENCY_CD` column of table `CURRENCY`. Now i want to set `MY_TBL.CURRENCY_CD` default for a value coming from `CURRENCY` table.how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a function to retrieve the default from another table, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[yourtable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_yourtable_col1]  DEFAULT ([dbo].[yourfunction]()) FOR [col1]
```